# Can't create/write to file (Errcode: 22)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Quite new with SQL I'm looking to export some data from a MySQL database into a csv file. I'm working locally (localhost).

Here is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
INTO
OUTFILE 'C:\Users\Martin\Downloads\result.csv'
FROM provider, location, provider_has_location
WHERE 
provider.idprovider = provider_has_location.provider_idprovider AND
location.idLocation = provider_has_location.location_idLocation
LIMIT 20
```

MySQL return the following error:

> Can't create/write to file 'C:UsersMartinDownloads esult.csv' (Errcode: 22)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the back-slashes may be affecting the command. Try using '\\' instead of '\'.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE condition INTO OUTFILE 'E:/test/filename.csv';

You are having issue with the back slash. Using forward slash resolved the issue in windows machine.
But in Ubuntu its not working.

Then I tried with the below mentioned Query and it works:

SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE condition INTO OUTFILE '//tmp/test/filename.csv';

Here the double slash when starting the path is necessary.