# Export the result of MySQL query to my PC as a CSV file

Tags: mysql, csv, export

I would like to export some MySQL-query results to my PC as a CSV-file. According to some contributions in the internet (e.g. [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-export-table-to-csv/)) it should work like the following:

```
mysql> SELECT 1,2,3,4,5 INTO OUTFILE 'C:\Users\MyPC\Desktop\numbers.csv';
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file 'C:\Users\MyPC\Desktop\numbers.csv' (Errorcode: 22 Invalid argument)
```

But theat leads to the given error. Waht am I doing wrong here? How can I save the output of my query as a csv ot a txt file?

P.S.: Im am using Windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't create/write to file (Errcode: 22)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369164/cant-create-write-to-file-errcode-22)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you didn't mention FROM which database you want the entrys.

```
SELECT 1,2,3,4,5 FROM ??????????????? INTO ...
```

With PHP you can do it like this:

```
$dz=fopen("file.csv", "w+");
$sql = "SELECT 1,2,3,4,5 FROM ?????????";
if ($result = $connectiontodatabase->query($sql)) {
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
fputs($dz, $row['1'] . "\t" . $row['2'] . "\t" . $row['3' . "\t" . $row['4'] . "\t" . $row['5'] . "\t\n");
}}
fclose($dz);
```

`$connectiontodatabase` of course needs to be the `new mysqli` statement

Comment: Those are just exemplary numbers, it returns those numbers as a result... Isn't there any way to do it without PHP?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I got the same error as you because of missing writing permissions to the dir. Have you checked if the mysql user has writing permission to the desired dir?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: You are using windows or linux?

Comment: Im am using windows 7

Comment: I think I have the permission, it is my private pc